# jQuery animate() not come from right to left

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

My problem is jquery animate - I want to make hover function, display:none div animate come from right to left. but it's come from left to right...

```
$('#index').hover(function(){
$(this).siblings('#indexhover').removeClass('hide').addClass('mostrar').addClass('show').animate({width: '140px',height:'121px'});
```

this link is demo,

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/G53nz/).

please hover to 'ana sayfa'

help me, thank you for solutions...

---

**Addendum (by TrueBlueAussie):**

To be helpful... here is a simple JSFiddle to get eveyone started :)

### http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/csE3L/1/

*The aim is to get the image to unveil/uncover itself (not slide) from the right instead of the left. Feel free to do this any way you wish, but please bear in mind the intended use.*

Comment: Animating from left is easy as it is just the width changing value. To animate from the right I believe you need to change position, size and margins at the same time (and have styling to hide the negative overflow). I look forward to suggested solutions as I need this myself :)

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your code?

Comment: Do you expect us to debug your site's source code? Please post here some relevant code and preferably a http://jsFiddle.net reproducing your issue.

Comment: @Itay: It's a pretty simple question. jQuery animation works from left to right (or top to bottom) only. He wants a version that operates right to left instead.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Above all, it's about online manners

Comment: @Itay: If it's *about online manners* "Do you expect us to debug your site's source code?" seems a little harsh to a newbie. Anyway they have provided a completely useless sample of code now, so you will be happier :)

Comment: Just trying to help him/her have a chance of getting an helpful answer.

Comment: what to change my friends for animate function ?

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
<div class="hover">
    <div class="image" style="display: none;position:relative;width: 0;left:400px;">
        <img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51nIbjQzQUL._SX385_.jpg" />
    </div>
Hover here</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('.hover').hover(function () {
    $('.image').show().css({width: 0}).animate({width: "400px",left:"0px"});
}, function () {
    var $image = $('.image');
    $image.animate({width: "0",left:"400px"}, function(){$image.hide()});
});
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/csE3L/2/)

Comment: The idea is to unveil/uncover it, without moving the image (they are not after a slide effect). Look at the demo site they gave as reference for what is intended.